# What vs command opens files in vscode from URI paths?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an array with paths to files in the workspace.
I would like to execute a command that opens all of these files. Which command do I use?

Here is an example of an array with my *paths*:
["/c:/Users/User/Desktop/Kod/extension/src/home.ts", /c:/Users/User/Desktop/Kod/extension/src/main.ts]

I send these paths from a webview that executes this function:

```ts
webviewView.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(async (data) => {
  const { tabPaths, name, isOpen } = data.value;
  switch (data.type) {
    case "onOpenTabs": {
      if (!data.value || !tabPaths) {
        return;
      }
      tabPaths.forEach(path => {
        vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.open", path);
      });
      break;
  }
});
```

I can confirm that I get the paths in my `onDidReceiveMessages`.
I then try the `vscode.open` command but I get this error message:

[image]

Is it the wrong command? Can I do something else?

Comment: is `path` a `vscode.Uri` object

Comment: One of the `window.openTextDocument` versions  followed by `window.showTextDocument` or just the `window.showTextDocument` that does both.

Comment: I store the paths like this:
`const paths = vscode.workspace.textDocuments.map(
        (element) => element.uri.path);`
Is that valid uri paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! ok. Thanks to [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark) and [rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8) I know the answer. I didn't save a valid textdocument.
Instead I just save an array of `vscode.workspace.textDocuments` as is. Like so:

```ts
const paths = vscode.workspace.textDocuments.map(
  (doc) => doc
);
```

Then open them with `vscode.window.showTextDocument` instead of `vscode.commands.executeCommand`. Like so:

```ts
paths.forEach(doc => {
  vscode.window.showTextDocument(doc);
});
```

So simple and it works. Thanks.